# Windows Scheduled Task not run as Powershell Scheduled Job

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

A Powershell Version 4 script does this:  it gets a download link from a webpage, downloads, the file and saves it to a dynamically created directory.  The script runs fine - initiated from a command line or by a Windows Scheduled Task.

Here are the Scheduled Task settings:

```
Program Script:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Add Arguments:
-NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "R:\powershell_scripts\downloadscript.ps1"

Start In:
R:\powershell_scripts\
```

I'd like to create a Scheduled Job from Powershell to create and manage the task as a Powershell Job.  I am able to do this as follows, problem is, the job (which shows up in as it should as a Windows Task) doesn't work.  It runs without error, but the script does not perform its functions.  I cannot figure out how to get the Powershell job script pass the arguments, like `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` for example into the task - or figure out whatever the problem may be.

This is how I tried:

```
#Trigger
$weeklywednesday = New-JobTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek Tuesday -At 17:00

#Script
$scriptPath = "R:\powershell_scripts\downloadscript.ps1"

Register-ScheduledJob -Name DownloadMyWebFile -FilePath $scriptPath -Trigger $weeklywednesday
```

Does anyone know why I can't get a script to run from a Scheduled Job when it works created as in Task Scheduler from Windows just fine?  Thank you.

Comment: Does the running user, of the task, have access to that mapped drive? Using mapped drives in tasks is not the best idea. PowerShell works fine with UNC paths.

Comment: @Matt, Yes.  I will try on local drive and report back.